# angular unit testing a $watch on an $attr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

From my understanding $attr.$observe fires once.  So there are times to use $watch on an attribute.   I am looking to unit test a directive that requires **ngModel**

```
scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function (newValue) {
            minlength = parseInt(attr.minLength);
            scope.minLengthValidator(newValue);
        });
```

Since this is using scope in the Link function it seems like I could call $digest.

My mocked attribute starts like so...

```
html = angular.element("<input ng-model=\"myUnit\" min-length=\"3\">");
```

I am not sure if I can just redefine element.attr('min-length') inside of my spec and run a $digest or if there is a more complex approach since the the watch is passing a new value.

the rest of my mock set up is like so

```
 $rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
 element = $compile(html)($rootScope);
 $rootScope.$digest(element);

 controller = element.controller('ngModel');
 scope = element.scope();
```

I have not tested a $watch on a attribute before so any direction that points me towards solving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, ...)` will create a watcher on `myUnit` scope property. Once the watcher is created, it isn't bound to `ngModel` attribute value.

It can be tested as any other scope watcher:

```
scope.myUnit = ...;
$rootScope.$digest();
expect(scope.minLengthValidator).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...);
```

> From my understanding $attr.$observe fires once.

No, `$attrs.$observe` observer will fire on each attribute change, it is preferable to `$scope.$watch`. As [the manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#attributes) states,

> Use $observe to observe the value changes of attributes that contain
>   interpolation (e.g. src="{{bar}}"). Not only is this very efficient
>   but it's also the only way to easily get the actual value because
>   during the linking phase the interpolation hasn't been evaluated yet
>   and so the value is at this time set to undefined.

The problem is that attributes belong to DOM and can't be tested cleanly. For controller specs `$attrs` local dependency can be mocked, but it isn't possible in directive specs. For testability reasons it is preferable to bind attributes to scope properties and test the scope only with no `$attrs` involved.